# Teechart paging Tool and Scrolling

Tags: activex, teechart

I have large amount of data so I have introduce a button in my application so that user can enable paging. This button works fine and paging also works fine unless Scrolling is done.once scrolling is done and after that if I do SetMaxPointsPerPage(0) it doesn't show me the entire points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to reset or initilize the paging after scroll has been done you should set the apropiate axis to automatic, by using the following code:

`TChart1.Axis.Bottom.Automatic = True
TChart1.Page.MaxPointsPerPage = 0`

regards !
Pep